# Using (+ve integer) + "some string " in printf?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf(2 + "abcdefgh");
}
```

How does this code print `cdefgh`? Compiler throws an error if I use `2-` or `2*` or any other operator.

Comment: It might make more sense if you know that `2 + any_pointer` is equal to `any_pointer + 2`, which is equal to `&any_pointer[2]`.

Comment: `"The format string is a character string, beginning and ending in its initial shift state"`

Comment: What were you even expecting with `2 * "abcdefgh"` anyway?

Comment: Very good reference link : http://computer-programming-forum.com/47-c-language/35ffff7cb4e79c86.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using string literals such as `"abcdefgh"` you actually have a pointer to a section on memory where this string resides. Basically you pass to `printf` a pointer to that location and instructs it to move the pointer 2 locations ahead, resulting in the a string starting from the 3rd char instead of the first

Note that you can use `-` but you need to use it like you do pointers arithmetic, like

`printf("abcdefgh" - 0); // using -N where N >0 would be UB`

So, this code is valid

```
int main()
{
    printf("abc\n" - 0);
    printf(1+"def");
    return 0;
}
```

but using `*,/` will not (also bitwise operators `|,&` will not be valid)

Answer (score 3):

In this code

```
printf(2 + "abcdefgh");
```

is the same as

```
printf(&("abcdefgh"[2]));
```

where, the argument serves as the format string in the `printf()`.

To elaborate, from the properties of *string literals*, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5/P6

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.<sup>78)</sup> The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>   type `char`, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence. [...]

and for an array, from chapter §6.3.2.1,

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

so, in case of the function call argument, as one of the arguments of addition operator, the string literal actually bols down to the address of the first element in the literal, and then, the addition, which is a **pointer arithmetic**, takes place. The result is in incremented pointer which points to the third element (C arrays are 0-based index).

That said, as emphasized in previous paragraph, a pointer arithmetic is only valid for *additive* operations, not Multiplicative operators.