# How can an integer and a string datatype be printed together with a '+' operator in printf()?

Tags: c, printf

The question given to me, asked for the output of the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf(5+"test_Quiz");
    return 0;
}
```

and correct answer/output is:

> Quiz

I don't understand the reason behind this output, how can I add an integer to a string? And even if I can, then why just "Quiz" is printed?

I have no idea on what basis can two different datatype can be operated on.

I expected an error for this.

Comment: `printf(5+"test_Quiz");` gives a pointer to `char`, which you add 5 to, so the output begins at the 6th character.

Comment: Replace 5 with some other numbers like 0, 1, 6, etc and see what the output is. That might give you a hint to what's going on

Comment: This quiz tests your knowledge of basic concept of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: For more: [What happens if I add an int with a plus sign after the string within printf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707276/what-happens-when-i-adding-an-int-with-a-plus-sign-after-the-string-within-print) **|** [Using (+ve integer) + "some string " in printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137396/using-ve-integer-some-string-in-printf?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -2):

### It is just pointer arithmetic

It does not print them together.
C doesn't know about String data type. Format string is passed to `printf()` like a character pointer `const char*` and arithmetic can work, so adding integer number to string format specifier (in this case) just tells compiler to increment value of pointer (not concatenate integer and String) and result will be that 5 characters of format string are skipped.

This gives the same result:

```
printf(5 + 10 - 10 +  "test_Quiz");
printf("test_Quiz" + 5)
```

Same works for character array:

```
char tq[] = "test_Quiz";
printf("String %s:", 5 + tq);
```

Compiler strips number of characters from format string, because call to `printf` is made with modified pointer to format string:

```
__printf (format=0x555555556009 "Quiz") at ./stdio-common/printf.c:2
```

In Hex dump of section '.rodata' we see that format string is at relative address 0x2004:

```
  0x00002000 01000200 74657374 5f517569 7a00     ....test_Quiz.
```

And compiler calls `printf()` with format string pointer relative address incremented by 5 (0x2009) in $rax:

```
1151:   48 8d 05 b1 0e 00 00    lea    0xeb1(%rip),%rax        # 2009 <_IO_stdin_used+0x9>
1158:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
115b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
1160:   e8 eb fe ff ff          call   1050 <printf@plt>
```

Comment: When you say "compiler in `printf()`", to me that implies to the user that this behavior is printf-specific, as opposed to being true for any kind of `char*`

Comment: It works not just with format string literals but char arrays.